# "Follow on" question vs edit to original - when to use which?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm interested in what guidance/advice can folks offer on when to edit questions to add more information vs asking a brand new follow-on question (that references the first one as a hyperlink)

I asked [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279316/what-exactly-makes-the-haskell-type-system-so-revered-vs-say-java) question which got quite a high rating and some really interesting comments. Having read some of the links that people provided in answers and comments, I'd like to ask a couple more questions - Basically, now I know a bit more than I did when I originally asked the question, I'd like to ask a slightly updated question.

my instinct is to ask another one, reference the first qn - but I'm interested to know if that's 'not the done thing' - main rationale is that I think edits are mainly for when it's clear people misunderstood what you originally meant or your question was too brief or poorly formed, which I don't think is the case here.

Comment: *"I think edits are mainly for when it's clear people misunderstood what you originally meant or your question was too brief or poorly formed"* - exactly, you shouldn't be editing a question once it's started getting answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have a follow-on question **always** ask a new question.

Editing your old question is not the way to go:

1. It potentially invalidates any existing answers.
2. People might not answer as they won't realise that you've tacked on a new bit to the question.
3. Chameleon questions annoy people and they *might* down-vote it.

You should include a link to your original question so that people know the context of what you're trying to do.