# Expanding a question with a related question

Tags: discussion

So I asked a simple question:

[How to list people belonging to a given group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055551/list-entities-belonging-to-an-association-in-doctrine/36055956?noredirect=1#comment59760992_36055956)

While working with one of the provided solutions, I realized I also needed an answer to a couple of related cases, them being:

- How to list people belonging to **NO** group?
- How to list people **NOT** belonging to a given group?

The answer to these questions can't be trivially derived from the answer to the prime question, yet it is interesting and potentially very useful to other members. **I will try to find the answer myself**, of course, but I think it would eventually belong in SO, either because I need to ask to solve it or as a a self-answered question.

So I find myself doubting which course of action to take to ask them:

1. **Add them to the question** Which I like about this is that very related questions are organized together and that's neat. What I don't like about this is that an "accepted" answer would require to answer the three of them. Someone could just know who to do one of the cases.
2. **Create standalone questions** What I don't like about this is the feeling that I'm duplicating information and that they don't seem connected when they actually are (for future visitors). Maybe I could create 3 questions and link them as "related"?
3. **????** A perfect solution I haven't thought of.

I don't know what to do, but I'm sure you do! So... tell me! :)

**EDIT**: This question has been marked as duplicate of [How to handle an OP's new issues that appear after answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296600/how-to-handle-an-ops-new-issues-that-appear-after-answering) which I don't think makes a lot of sense because they are different both in scope and angle. 
Could more likely be a duplicate of ["Follow on" question vs edit to original - when to use which?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290746/follow-on-question-vs-edit-to-original-when-to-use-which), but I still don't think that's the case, because they are not follow up question, but closely related questions.

**EDIT 2**: I added the previous EDIT mark because I don't know better. If there is a better channel for that discussion, please, embarrass me by pointing at it with a huge arrow.

Comment: Don't do that. Please. The issue is that sort of behavior is commonly attributed to 'help vampires', those people who get their initial answer and then prey upon their audience to drag their simple question out into multiple non-trivial questions and want answers for all of them, right there.  You don't want to be labeled as a help vampire.  The better thing to do is not use Stack Overflow all your problems, but rather only your most pressing.  You've identified extra things you want; go try them on your own and after you've run into trouble and have a separate question; ask it separately.

Comment: Also, if a new question comes to your mind, please don't immediately ask it on SO. Do some research first (either on SO or, even better, using Google). Maybe your question has already been asked and answered somewhere.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Sure, I will do that but even if I do solve it myself I think it would be an interesting enough question to be in Stack Overflow, even if it is self-answered, wouldn't it? Also, by *don't do that* you mean "dont do *any*" of the 3 provided options? It's hard to cast a boolean to a <select> option... hehe

Comment: @honk Isn't it the common behaviour? I mean, even for the most lazy users is way more quick/comfortable to search (at least) a couple of times in the internet that composing a well-written question in SO and *waiting*... isn't it? ^^U

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz I think GeorgeStocker was referring to option 1 primarily. In many cases, asking and self-answering a question is perfectly fine, and even encouraged. However, please make sure that your follow-up question is actually a good one (as specified by the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) and that there are no duplicates, otherwise there's no sense in another question existing.

Comment: @MageXy of course, that comes without saying. Actually, if the question existed, I wouldn't (have to) create it in the first place, because of the **path of least resistance** principle :)

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz First doing the research and trying to find an answer yourself, though as you say most times faster despite the fast reaction you get here once you post, is still too often not even attempted... it's sad. Even eschewing the effort of actually writing at least a barely-acceptable question, as such abusers often do, doesn't change that.