# Is it acceptable to rollback a question to remove an additional question?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

Earlier I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622557/find-a-word-inside-an-array-using-textbox-input) where the OP had been given an answer and accepted it, then hours later updated their question to ask a new question.  Also note, the new question was added at the request of the person with the accepted answer, though it's more or less unrelated.

I left a comment letting them know they should simply ask a new question and not add questions to their original post which already has an accepted answer. Would it be acceptable to edit/rollback the OP's question to *remove* the newly added question?

Comment: I'd say yes but since the OP is arguing it's not a new question it may just lead to an edit war. You might want to try explaining how it's a new problem (and therefore requires a new question) first.

Comment: Looks like [the additional question was added as suggested by the answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622557/find-a-word-inside-an-array-using-textbox-input#comment94109794_53623396)...

Comment: @AndrewT. - yes I'm aware and mentioned that in my question "*Also note, the new question was added at the request of the person with the accepted answer, though it's more or less unrelated.*" That definitely gave me pause to do anything here, but it looks like they are both a bit new so could benefit from a better understanding of how the site works.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254814/op-keeps-asking-more-questions-based-on-a-single-question-which-was-answered-alr

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290746/follow-on-question-vs-edit-to-original-when-to-use-which/290747

Comment: "EDIT: Adjusted code but now I get error *xxx*" → Close for making us iteratively debug.

Comment: Hi All. Thanks for your input regarding protocols on SO. If you look at my profile I have been on here for less than a month.

Comment: I saw it as still problem solving the original issue and so was continuing to help as I am wanting to help others to develop their skill like others have helped me and I learn plenty in the process. I will however encourage askers to create a new question in the future.

Comment: @Josh: you may want to look up "help vampire" here on Meta. Mind you, I'm not statin' your OP was diagnosed as one – but still, better keep a stake nearby.

Comment: @BSMP - your first hunch was correct. Despite having been informed that a new question is in order, the OP went back and made a second edit to revive the *"I'm receiving this error now"* version. But they also mentioned this: *"I'm not able to create a new question"*. Were they cut off from asking a new question? I'm not sure when and why that happens.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, because otherwise the question would become *too broad*. [The user should open a second question instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290746/545127).